# SQL update records with incrementing value starting from 1 each time

Tags: sql, sql-update, auto-increment

I am adding batches of records to a table using a single insert statement.  I want each new batch to be allocated incrementing numbers, but starting from 1 each time.

So, if I have

```
Batch    Name    IncementingValue
1        Joe     1
1        Pete    2
1        Andy    3
2        Sue     1
2        Mike    2
2        Steve   3
```

and I then add two records (using a single insert statement) :

```
3        Dave
3        Paul
```

How can I run an update statement against this table so that Dave will be set to 1 and Paul to 2.  I don't want to use a cursor.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you targetting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ranking function `ROW_NUMBER` should do what you need. You didn't mention any specific rules about how the sequence number should be allocated, so I've done it here using the name:

```
INSERT targetTable(Batch,Name,IncementingValue)
SELECT BatchId,
       Name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name)
FROM sourceTable
```

Comment: @Ed - do you know if I can apply these values via an update statement e.g.
update SegmentationKeysUnconstrained 
set batchrownumber=row_number() over (order by trackingtokenid)
from SegmentationKeysUnconstrained
where batchid='58D73880-31B1-40AF-A749-7F6EBEAAF3E4'

Comment: The problem I have is that I need to apportion one set of row_number() values over several insert statements, so I can't actually use row_number at the point of insertion - I have to do it once several inserts have completed.

Comment: The following did the trick:
UPDATE    derivedtable
SET    batchrownumber = rowno
FROM    (
        SELECT    batchrownumber,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY batchid ORDER BY trackingtokenid) AS rowno
        FROM    SegmentationKeysUnconstrained
  where batchid='58D73880-31B1-40AF-A749-7F6EBEAAF3E4'
    ) AS derivedtable

Answer (score 0):

I needed to accomplish something similar with dates and formatted numbers.

Hopefully, someone will find this example useful.

```
    update TEST_TABLE 
    set ref = reference
          from (
                      select 
                          *, 
                          (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),12) + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)) as reference 
                      from TEST_TABLE
                      WHERE 
                    test_table.id > 4
                        and
                    test_table.id < 8 
                ) TEST_TABLE
```